# custom field focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, focus

I created one customUi class in that im creating 3 fiels as 1 label and two button fileds....

so i m creating the customui and passing the filed names...

like

```
public class CustomTextField extends Manager {

    Field field ;
//passing 3 names to the construcor

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int fieldCount = getFieldCount();
        int screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
        int yOffset =0;
        for(int i=0; i<fieldCount; i++)
        {

        field= getField(i);
        layoutChild(field, screenWidth, 100 );
        setPositionChild(field, (screenWidth-field.getWidth())>>1, yOffset);
        yOffset += field.getHeight()+5;
            }

        setExtent(screenWidth, yOffset);
    }

protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
        if(field.isFocus())
        {
        //g.setBackgroundColor(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        int oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.DARKBLUE);
        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), Graphics.ALL_ROUNDED_RECT_CORNERS, 60, 60);
        g.setColor(oldColor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: CustomTextField(string name,string name,string name){addding three fields}    in hte mainscreen class im creating 3 customfields of this class...but i m getting focus problem on selecting each one....

Comment: -1. This is a really poorly written question. At a minimum, the first comment should be moved into the question so there's actually a question being asked. But overall it needs a bunch of cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override `paintBackground(Graphics g)` inside of the manager. Override it inside of the child field class. It's responsibility of a child field how to present its focused state.